# Getting NaN as output in my display only item oracle

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-5

I am getting NaN as output in Display only field..

Below is my query which is in page (function and global variable)

In this i am getting NaN for the item when the value having comma like 1,500.0 :P2510_OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT

Comment: Which value is '1,500.0' - match_value or unalloc_value? The handling for match_value looks OK (I think), but you aren't removing commas from unalloc_value before converting that to Number; so if that has a comma group separator that will end up as NaN?

Comment: Hi i mentioned already the item name, its for unalloc_value.....  the value is for 1,500.00

Comment: how to remove commas from unalloc_value in my Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to remove commas from unalloc_value in my Javascript

The same way you already do with `match-value` -

```
    match_value = match_value.replace(/,/g, '');
    match_value = Number(match_value, 10);
    unalloc_value = Number(unalloc_value, 10); // BQ4-5024
```

Just add another replace:

```
    match_value = match_value.replace(/,/g, '');
    match_value = Number(match_value, 10);
    unalloc_value = unalloc_value.replace(/,/g, '');
    unalloc_value = Number(unalloc_value, 10); // BQ4-5024
```